# 1D irregular grid to 1d regular grid

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to interpolate values in a 1D array from an irregular grid to a regular grid. For example, imagine that the original data has values at irregularly spaced X coordinates:

```
source_x = np.asarray([127.3, 759.4, 1239.1, ..., 98430.1])
source_y = whatever(x) # No really a function but a set of masurements
```

The destination grid is also 1D, but the X coordinates are regularly spaced along the axis:

```
dest_x = np.arange(250, 100000, 500)
```

I want to find the distance and index of the two closest elements in the original `source_x`coordinates array for every point the destination `dest_x`coordinates array. For example:

```
dest_x[0] = 250
indices = [0, 1]
distances = [250-127.3, 759.4-250]
```

This should be done as an atomic operation if possible.

My first idea was to use `scipy.spatial.KDTree`, but this doesn't allow 1D data. Any other options?

EDIT

There is an "ugly" option that involves a "dummy" coordinate of zeros, which allows using `scipy.spatial.KDTree`:

```
source_x = np.asarray([127.3, 759.4, 1239.1, ..., 98430.1])
source_dummy = np.zeros_like(source_x)

dest_x = np.arange(250, 100000, 500)
dest_dummy = np.zeros_like(dest_x)

src = np.vstack((source_x, source_dummy)).T
dst = np.vstack((dest_x, dest_dummy)).T

tree = KDTree(src)
distances, indices = tree.query(dst, 2)
```

However, I don't like this approach that much...

Comment: For linear interpolation, just use `numpy.interp()`. If you need the indices themselves, use `numpy.searchsorted()`. The only tricky bit is handling grid values that are outside your data range. Distances are easy to compute once you have the indices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `numpy.searchsorted`is a good approach to find the indices in 1D arrays, and the weights (distances) are also easily computed before.

Comment: @RobertKern Your comment is the answer! You could post it as an official answer so that the people can find it faster...

Answer (score 2):

For linear interpolation, just use `numpy.interp()`. If you need the indices themselves, use `numpy.searchsorted()`. The only tricky bit is handling grid values that are outside your data range. Distances are easy to compute once you have the indices.